# Failed to run mongo.so after upgrading php to 5.4.10

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I get this error when viewing a php page using mongo: **"Mongo could not be loaded"**

and my command line says this:

```
/usr/lib/php5/20100525# php -i | fgrep -i configure
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

So I've ensured both `20090626` and `20100525` directory have mongo.so and restarted apache but it still wont work. I'm very confused. I've tried reinstalling with no luck.

Edit:

I've made sure both directories have the same extensions and now I get this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
root@ip-172-31-16-45:/usr/lib/php5#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've upgraded your PHP binary, you will need to re-compile the MongoDB driver. Note the PHP development headers (e.g. `php5-dev` package on Ubuntu) should match the PHP binary (on the off chance you only updated the binary and not the development files). Assuming you used PECL, the following should recompile the driver:

```
$ sudo pecl install -f mongo
```

Comment: Thank you, this set me on the right track, to fix it i did the folllowing: sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear; sudo pecl install -f mongo; Fixed, thank you